# ExtJs 4.2.4 isValid in custom Validator: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: extjs

I have custom validator for my "editor" field. There I want check if this filed is valid and also check whether my fields equivalent to each other. But when I add this.confirmationEditor.isValid() in my validator I get this error: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

```
 Ext.define('My.view.common.MyPanelBase', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    constructor: function (config) {
        if (config) {
            Ext.applyIf(config.editorConfig, {allowBlank: false,
        maskRe: /[0-9]/,
        regex: /^[0-9]+$/,
        enforceMaxLength: true,
        maxLength: 6,
        anchor: '95%',
        inputType: 'password'});
        }
        Ext.apply(this.config, config);
        this.initializeEditors();
        this.initConfig();
    },

    initializeEditors: function () {
        this.editor = Ext.create('Ext.My.TextField', Ext.apply(this.config.editorConfig, {
            validator: this.editorValidator.bind(this),
            fieldLabel: this.config.editorLabel
        }));
        this.confirmationEditor = Ext.create('Ext.My.TextField', Ext.apply(this.config.editorConfig, {
            validator: this.confirmationEditorValidator.bind(this),
            fieldLabel: this.config.confirmationEditorLabel
        }));
    },

    confirmationEditorValidator: function () {
       //here I get the error
        return this.confirmationEditor.isValid() && this.compareFields();
    },

    compareFields: function () {
        return //some logic
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just infinitely calling `confirmationEditorValidator` function for your `confirmationEditor` with `this.confirmationEditor.isValid()`.

[`validator`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-validator) config of `Ext.form.field.Text`

> A custom validation function to be called during field validation (getErrors).

[`getErrors()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-getErrors) method called within [`isValid()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Field2.html#Ext-form-field-Field-method-isValid)